# iOS: Polyfill NFC web API - is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket, tcp

I'm facing migrating my iOS [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html) based app to PWA. The primary issue is that it is using NFC scanner. I have started to wonder if there is any way to polyfill [NFC web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_NFC_API) on iOS / Safari? It seems that official support will not happend soon...

At the moment I'm thinking of creating some kind of "service" that would host native NFC API over some communication channel.

A bit more detailed:

1. Create an app/service that would be a proxy for native NFC API.
2. The app should receive scan requests send scan results over browser reachable interface (Sockets?).
3. At PWA side I think it could be nicely packed into NFC web API shape.
4. Native app would be required to install with my PWA. But can also be considered general proxy for PWA class apps.

I'm not familiar with iOS programming and architecture but it seems there are some basic flaws of this concept. So here are my questions to iOS devs :)

1. Is is possible to implement and run continually some kind of service like TCP / sockets server?
2. Do you have an idea which layer would be suitable to handle communication between NFC proxy and PWA?
3. Maybe you have some alternatives to proposed approach?

IT Man

Comment: That approach isn't going to work. Assuming you need Bluetooth or IP connection to your scanner you will need to write a native app for iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually Bluetooth is not a case here. Both proxy (native iOS app) and PWA will be installed on the same device. The communication is more like IPC (Inter Process) but restricted to connection layer of PWA (browser capabilities).

Comment: I was talking about communication between the NFC reader (assuming you are not using the NFC hardware in the iOS device) and your app. Regardless there is no inter-process communication aside from opening the other app via a URL scheme (which means the two apps would keep  popping to the front).  Apart from limited background modes, only one app runs at a time on iOS. You could possibly use a shared database file,but again this is only available to native apps, not PWA. In my opinion PWA is to restricted on iOS for most purposes.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm assuming phone build-in NFC scanner will be used. I'm not thinking about third party scanner. I think the real problem You've pointed is that I cannot run service (nfc proxy app) in the background. Maybe I could pass scan request from PWA to NFC proxy app over url scheme. Tthat would trigger scan begin (since that moment ui would be blocked with "system" prompt until dismiss or tag scanned).But how to send scan result back to PWA and activate it back to screen (once this would be doable, proxy could be closed)?